# Active Directory User Name Convention?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, naming-conventions, powershell-3.0

I am automating Active Directory user creation in Powershell and am confused on what the `-name` parameter for `New-ADUser` accepts as valid. My predecessors have manually entered names for years as such: "Last, First M.". Well I get an error when I try this because it doesn't like the comma.

I've looked at forums such as [IBM's](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPREK_6.1.0/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_admin607.htm) on proper user naming conventions and what invalid characters there are. It says use an escape character for commas, fair enough.

But what I don't understand is when I manually go to a user and click rename, I can enter something like "/@$,.!?>" and it is perfectly accepted as a name.

Comment: It would help to read the documentation (from `Get-Help New-ADUser -Parameter Name`): Specifies the name of the object. This parameter sets the Name property of the Active Directory object. The LDAP Display Name (ldapDisplayName) of this property is "name".  The following example shows how to set this parameter to a name string. `-Name "SaraDavis"`

Comment: I've seen that and I still don't understand, so if I set `-Name` to something normal like "jsmith" how then do I get it to display in AD as "Smith, John M"

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `New-ADObject` for that:

```
New-ADObject -Name 'Last, First M.' -Type User `
-OtherAttributes @{SamAccountName = "YouSamAccountName"}
```

Also make sure to set the `Path` Parameter, otherwise the default is the root of the domain

Answer (score 0):

You can use new-aduser -Name "John Smith" -DisplayName "Smith, John" -GivenName John -surname smith -Samaccountname "Jsmith"

-Name is a required parameter for new-adobject